# ECharts how to set symbols from series in tooltip?

Tags: javascript, visualization, echarts

Is there any way to use already existed icons from echarts in echarts tooltip?

[Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=MYewdgzgLgBAJgQwJ4RgXhgbQOQFlzYA0M2AKgK4CmRJA6pXDWQBblMBiATgJZMDKCKP3JhsAXQDcAKCkgADlG7h0MAN5SYMRVAA2lAFxqNmrZQAeUQ9j5QEwANYMYAGW5hqxgL6FjUECB1FOUN1Ey0eAHMIyk4rBDNuCGwvH009aLA4EONNRFtDHABRAFsEbh0mAFUwJTAYAEE4JOJsADVuOEoQBqamABFuTkpgIRa-SgROYGYYQrAIt2oxVJMQHkowSxJmNe4AL3BbCpXNAHpTmF2NrewANxjFYARjnJhzmGfuCLArPQAzUavPzBEgARgADABSIivd7_LYiTp_RZwE5vC6RZhbCGENB4_EEtCwi4Adw6UGYVlB0LR72YlC-WMMAGZwbSLlBzFAbEg9Nkwu9NGS4BTDAAWNnE1b3Th_HQgElWABGQwQ9hhAou3hSxgiPCyRjC8KszJpr0xN1BACYzWFQJsymBnAglZQdIYoJwqDrNH4AkqQGZ-SY_hMoOQhsGwhAEPd6hAAJKlaIhTyvNOabWaMz1BIQKNaJByAwkJ6ciJrJAakzvAOIyZIADiCBBf2eEEoaLyCEMiBQaIgch03CgADlyMVXbEYFa0fFEqRuA4C5pPt9aCPmM7Xe7wt6wlmTPOIK53CvLmAAFoxEAer2UdM-mBIXOJAvvKBFkvYeURauaMAEGKb8EAgJoEEYNFAOA5wQDLWorGKDo4D0f8YGgyhmxBAA2ABWdkYFKIMYFZSVNUItxDAATjIkxB2HMcJynQx8NeX8ACFQJLWdXmPbc3XPP41lKKBOWnAAKW5nioABKdAAD5DTCEwhnDTg6iknQqAAOj8WCnj0GweHmcSZOkZSYEPTMVkPbtL38YoCleUJlM_YsrAgYdOk4NDNGgSYtitWiwg2A0AA5gpDcoxPwTorDAcBqDRXJBAQTiHD1EBEXPNJFh5PklIszRQHladsBJZgRw8IrLOSo9VXyksXJqkq1isCqquSGqM2Uqy6LdYZOTgPpUvS-xMuywrlOHdxGpykxWrKjrOS6oq-rCSYJjmqaLMW9rKpW14DyOyzH00ZZjA7dZ8ywZyTowqwSjKF4LLc78ZqSk7uwKa02RgUFmVnf7wVBYgAbFYgaOIK1WWhiELosnQXQEna6J2RU907E71pgJGd2dJAsq2P4RBGWoYHE7s5Oa5T7QgAJKG039KdSszsfTNEaYAoDv2qcnGmaE63t-RZfPgVKCitIKwbCoHQSo0GZ2ZCGZyh_7iGZeGObuiyHpIdpOm6AWxeFkgPrF76sFBXC_phoGgsV62Vflv7mVhmAxS1g9OfunmrAGIYRhNr8RfcC2JawQHXcBjWQeIMByB0HQNbVt3XaCsRtbCLn0L9khxkmaZZnmUW6tNn9S6-iPMFlv6E6TyG45gKjlbBq01YB93QQi8EEem5Hdxzvz0bvfderqiAkEnAI-H2EtrQnqeA13bA4G4IDwEgk7Sk4exTyak6UvyW6auzw-ir17B65e0-whfPMWPBSLb7xlGh9PoTOBEsSrFUJVPDFrfOQIAIAjgQiQfynBAS3wsnICCa95gFD-n9CEyC-4wJrBiJclJUYYNrPNW-goYBwLgAgiIhgITn0IVqKhRV3g9QwTjGqH1trvxagENqJAhhbwwWEYUop1a0O9kI2qIi2HKXvm-GANtn6n0vqFBRmRAFFVfoPERYRgGgMUOARCyFUJ1Vvp_b-MRf7_3EqoYAngZLKJqvwnBEoDGnxADKOUCplSqnsPUJONiipr38mAYAJZMDS2BugmBTCVF5U_AVcRu0OFlW4T4iydiKGOIshE4RGDYkmEvpA6BvDJE3QAOxPzSf3HcBCipGMED_Egf8AFlNgSAsBOiIG2CgUk5SEAR6Y0acpPxtgAlBJCagsJt8MkmAmZobJmhCmGBKbImq8jMgxjgDAUKoE1kbLAqBTpaQB6VKaVo8B2BQp7JDMJGpJi6n_3OZoZxMRXEY2wCqCYnjvF9L4eSexizT4DIQEMyWf1sK90-SYEhZCkHEBQaUmAoL1EqWwYcuhFwlTIoskQiFbhyHAwReRBhvCCXjLBSw6JB9eELXiVYRJYKpmnRqpndJZ0YCZ08NIKQxQkAAGFmABW0uAcSq9Ur2RAMUGg4k4GcCAhAOSaBFIuU5TyvlHYoAAHkFC1HMa8OZqMiIsifpFHqVjzIwDprAHMeZCgWGuCoRVvKoGvG0tEKAsU3SmUdc6rlorgHuE2IKwp2AZKOuPNpCABlGbOqtZyP1MlMCgkkMYOmDMmYgAiIKi1iQo3XBoBmiAWbNhs2KuAaAlwNXKAwHavlzr1XaLAKZE1Sa9AprTdgY8NB5C1u0oUtmxqZDvDNTAXN-bYAVu5faqATrKAupAJ0HQplJ1QC9cUH11x_WviSGzftxbk3MyHdagtEggA&version=5.4.3)

[image]

We see empty circles and diamond in points and in legend, but in tooltip is always fill circles. How to set same icons in tooltip as icons in series?

Answer (score 0):

I havent found an easy inbuilt way to do it.

If you want this feature by all means you could use the [tooltip formatter function](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#tooltip.formatter) and input the corresponding svg path for each symbol.

Heres a small [example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWsAeBBDEDOAXMmurGAJ4gCmRA5AMYCGYVA5sAE7m0A0J6AE2aMiAbVoBZGL1i0AKgFcqM2gHUqAlXIAWClQDEOEFQGVmphdFoBdEgF8-6cjnxFUpMpRqyAbowA2SrT2jmTAwP6QIG78sABmnAC2zCwcRCx4YKEOJHhURlSEsKKx7h6wQmAixQCMAKwADDywAEwAzE2tLQAszS01ABzNNW11w90A7H0AbA3WoR4U1HT-ENDKsXYktnYA3CgocZb0kDBkhWAAFCCMHIyJeACUxOgcVGAKHHC0ADwCED4AHw_PA-VjAm5gbTxCD-fzwABEAGIGg0Jg04m0ERVEYlRjwGrAfKNYNoALQk4mE7SUkk0wk-Cl1UmUinUplEjkALwRwIA9JDtPzQeC8MBElRzhgwLBOLAAO7aZhUHz5AB0sEysP8sHWGjwmvFkoSHGSYEg0FYCs4AGsfnz_kDgnYgA) to give you an idea.

You could also file a feature request on [github](https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues) but I doubt it will be implemented in the near future. But then again, you could always implement it yourself and open a pull request.